# CSS position:absolute not covering position:relative text and borders

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a problem with position:absolute inside position:relative divs.
I've been reading about CSS positioning, stacking context and related questions here, but nothing seems to solve my problem after playing with position and z-index.

With the following structure:

```
<div id='container1'>
    <div id='wrap1'>
        <div id='item1'>item1</div>
        <div id='hid1'>hidden1</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='container2'>
    <div id='wrap2'>
        <div id='item2'>item2</div>
        <div id='hid2'>hidden2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where "wrap" divs are relative and "hid" divs are absolute and not shown until hovering the "wrap" ones. The problem is that I want the hidden divs to appear in front of everything, but due to their order "hid1" does not cover "wrap2" text and borders.

How can I avoid that? If possible without modifying the container divs since "wrap" will be two instances of the same injected code.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucpphabb/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use z-index CSS property for this. But make sure, z-index only works when you've specified a position.

```
#hid1, #hid2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1337;
    /* other CSS code */
}
```

Comment: It wasn't working for me because I was setting a z-index for "wrap" too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just give a higher `z-index` value .[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucpphabb/1/)

```js
$('#wrap1').hover(
                function() { $('#hid1').show(); },
                function() { $('#hid1').hide(); }
            );
$('#wrap2').hover(
                function() { $('#hid2').show(); },
                function() { $('#hid2').hide(); }
            );
```

```css
#wrap1,#wrap2{
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#hid1 {
    z-index:100;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    top:2px;
    background-color:cyan;
}
#hid2 {
    z-index:100;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    top:-10px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    background-color:cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container1'>
    <div id='wrap1'>
        <div id='item1'>item1</div>
        <div id='hid1'>hidden1</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='container2'>
    <div id='wrap2'>
        <div id='item2'>item2</div>
        <div id='hid2'>hidden2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now I see that it didn't work for me because I was setting a z-index for "wrap" too. Thanks! Accepting the other answer for brevity, but will upvote.